# How to log parameter from yml config file %region% via monolog

Tags: php, symfony, properties, yaml, monolog

I tried to use formatter:

```
services:
monolog.formatter.tits:
    class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
    arguments:
        - "[%%datetime%%] [%extra.region%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%%: %%message%% %%context%% %%extra%%\n" "%region%"
```

But i failed and get this:

```
[2016-02-23 09:56:54][%region%] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

there is [%region%] instead my region parameter from yml config file.

How to make this run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found answer.

```
services:
monolog.formatter.q3dm6:
    class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
    arguments:
        - "[%%datetime%%] [region:%region%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%%: %%message%% %%context%% %%extra%%\n"
```

You need only one % if you want to pull it from yml config file. Now I getting right log:

```
[2016-02-23 10:50:38] [region:pl] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double your '%' around the extra.region parameter to make it work:

```
services:
monolog.formatter.tits:
class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
arguments:
    - "[%%datetime%%] [%%extra.region%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%%: %%message%% %%context%% %%extra%%\n" "%%region%%"
```